# Rails - How to show an unordered list list from the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design

I have a question about how to pull a list from a database.  I am using sqlite for development and postgres for production (I know I need to use pg in development too - it's on the list) :)  I am also using simple_form.

My app can be seen here: [majorfinder.com](http://www.majorfinder.com/) and I'm working on the majors section.  For each major show page I have a few lists I want to show.

I have information that I need output from the database into an unordered list.  The unordered list is the Typical Major Courses for that major and it would look something like this(if the major you were looking at was Linguistics, for instance):

```
<ul>
  <li>Phonetics and Phonology</li>
  <li>Syntax</li>
  <li>Semantics and Pragmatics</li>
  <li>Language in Society</li>
</ul>
```

The classes for each major will be different for each major and will therefore be information I need to place in the database. How would you recommend I store this information in the database and then how to retrieve it into my views?  The number of list items might vary but not by much - sometimes there might be 2 list items and other times there might be 5.

---

UPDATE: Put the classes in a table with each class relating back to a specific major.  The relationship would look like this:

Major.rb

> has_many :major_classes

MajorClass.rb

> belongs_to :major

The major_class schema would look like this:

```
create_table "major_classes", :force => true do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.integer  "major_id"
  t.text     "class_name", :unique => true, :null => false
end
```

In my controller I would do this:

```
@major_class = MajorClass.includes(:major)
```

I'm new to rails and I'm not sure how I would pull this into my view.. Can you help?

Is this how you would do it?  Or would you make any changes to this?  Thanks!!

Comment: Why are you so paranoid about doing things the right way?why do you keep asking, is this how you would do it?? Make mistakes, that's when you will learn. Now, go ahead and create what you have done and get it working right. As to how I would display it in the view, i follow this rule in rails, "CONTROLLER means in simple words, instance variable(@variable) setter". That is in an action I would set the @major variable and it will have all that I want to display in my page. In my view, I will iterate that variable using .each. I have shown this in my answer. Try everything before you die!

Comment: I was simply asking your advice.  Paranoia has nothing to do with it.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hey, Im very sorry, if thats rude. But, if you ask me, I still work with the code that was written by me, 2 years before. Believe me, I now know like a 500 things that you shouldn't be doing. I wanted you to taste that essence of learning it the hard way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists Model

```
 list_id | list_name                  | child_of
    ------------------------------------------------
    1       | Linguistics                | 0
    2       | Phonetics and Phonology    | 1
    3       | Syntax                     | 1
    4       | Semantics and Pragmatics   | 1
    5       | Language in Society        | 1
    6       | Arts                       | 0
    7       | Music                      | 6
    8       | Dance                      | 6
    9       | Drama                      | 6
```

**controller**

```
@list = Lists.where(:child_of => Lists.find_by_list_name("Linguistics").list_id)
```

**view**

```
<ul>

@list.each do |i|

  <li><%= i.list_name %></li>

end

</ul>
```

Though rails migration methods are sophisticated, nothing beats the old school mysql create table statements. If I'm not using create table, then I'm not working with databases.

**migration_file.rb**

```
class CreateLists < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
        execute "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS lists"
        execute <<-SQL
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lists (
                list_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                list_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                child_of INT(11) NOT NULL
                created_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
                updated_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (list_id),
                UNIQUE(list_name)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
        SQL
  end
  def down
        execute "DROP TABLE lists"
  end
end
```

Comment: I can see how this would work great, beck03076!  What does the migration look like to create the child_of?

Comment: Edited the answer, addded a migration.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it.  So, create a new table with a relation to the majors table.  I've updated my question to show my db schema as I would create it and the relationship between tables.  Would you take a look and see if this is what you would do or if there's anything you would change?

Answer (score -1):

Static data can be created as a resource class:

```
rails g model Degree name
```

and can be populated in the `db/seed.rb` file.

After you run your migrations and the `seed.rb` file has been updated you can add the records to the table using

`rake db:seed`

In the controller action where you want to use the values add:

```
@degrees = Degree.all
```

and `@degrees` will include all the records.

Comment: Thanks Richard!  I am not very familiar with seed data but I think I may not have been very clear about what I am looking for.  I've updated my question.  Is this still what you would recommend?

Comment: Hmm, ok, that's different.  In terms of DB design it looks like you've got `Class`, `Major`, and `Degree` models with a relationships between them.  `Major` has_many `Classes` and has_many `Degrees` off the top of my head.

Comment: Actually it is much simpler than this.  I only have a major class and I simply want to show information about each major.  If you look at this page here is a major: http://majorfinder.com/majors/web-design you will see near the top a 'Typical Major Courses' with a list of a few.  This is static right now I want to make it dynamic.  That's my first question.

Comment: My second question relates to one of the tabs 'Interesting Facts'.  I have an area called Degree Options where I want to list which degrees area available with this major.  Sorry that I wasn't more clear!  I hope that makes sense now.  Thanks for your help!!